# Different flavors of maps from open street view Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a leaflet map that I will with this:

```
$('#map').height($(window).height()-64+'px');
            var map = L.map('map' , { zoomControl:false }).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'bottomright' }).addTo(map);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);
```

This gives a greyscale kinda boring map. I am trying to get a more colorful one for open street view like the one in the below link of you click on the layers and click "streets"

http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a colored OSM map, change your `L.tileLayer` function with this

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});
```

[Here](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html) is a complete list of various basemap providers for leaflet.

Check [this](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) link as well